# PHP internals - what error logging function to use?

Tags: php, c

I'm writing a PHP extension (although its starting to look a lot like a zend extension). There are instances where it needs to write to a logging interface.

I see that zend_error() is being used elsewhere however:

- reading the source code on github I found zend_error declared in zend/zend.h but I couldn't find the corresponding definition of the function
- looking at the contexts in which zend_error is used, I suspect that calls will be rerouted/diverted by set_error_handler

Normally, the logging will happen in MINIT and MSHUTDOWN (where presumably an error handler defined by a script cannot have any influence) but there may be times in between as well - and I'm looking for some consistency. Hence trying to understand how the mechanism works.

Is it safe to use zend_error() in MINIT/MSHUTDOWN?

How do I ensure that I am always calling the the default error handler?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: I will probably be implementing this on 7.2 - are you suggesting that the internal API has changed recently? This is not in the documentation I've read - can you provide more info?

Answer (score 5):

Well, I found this in the [PHP Wiki](https://wiki.php.net/internals/review_comments).  I think this is old, but I imagine it still applies to Zend3:

> **Don't use zend_error**
>
> zend_error() should only be used inside the engine. Inside PHP
>   extensions only PHP's error functions shoudl be used. Typically
>   php_error_docref() is the best choice. php_error_docref() will extend
>   the error message by extra information, like the current function name
>   and properly escape output where needed. zend_error() is used by the
>   Zend Engine due to PHP's modular architecture where the Zend Engine
>   and TSRM should be compilable without other parts of PHP. The engine
>   therefore can not use PHP level APIs. This limitation does not exist
>   in extensions.

What this says to me is that zend_error was written for use in the engine and not designed as one of the tools for use in building extensions.  For that reason, you are unlikely to find documentation covering the details you are asking about, and, even if it DOES work reliably for you, it may not continue to do so.

Comment: Up voted as this was really useful - but I'm still looking for a way of logging events which cannot be overridden from the PHP source code.

Comment: Why you would want to avoid allowing the PHP app to do custom error handling on your error?

Comment: Because I want to interfere with the code loading process and have a consistent audit trail - if the code replaces set_error_hander() then the behaviour of subsequent include/require will be different from earlier load operations.

Comment: Well, its your project, but I think it's better to use the well established and carefully maintained PHP logging/error structure, and just document (or deal with) the impact of another developer's interactions.  "caveat coder"  Anyway, best luck either way you go!